# Combine multiple SQL statements into one stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Okay from these two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sessions
JOIN Sessions ON Sessions.ID = Sessions.SessionID
```

I need to count how many seats are taken (counting how many of each `sessionID` exist)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Sessions.SessionID, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionID) AS Sess
FROM 
    Sessions
WHERE 
    UserID = @UserId
```

And then if the count `Sess` is less (an `int` column in table), select only those sessions from my join (below code is not correct):

```
SELECT *
FROM Sessions
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

How do I combine all of these statements into one stored procedure?

Each select statement works on its own, but I don't know how to combine this into one solution.

Comment: Why can't you just add `JOIN Sessions ...` into the middle query?

Comment: Please show relevant sample data and expected output, as well as your attempt so far

Comment: You have removed all your code, making your question impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH EligibleSessions As (
    SELECT s.ID
    FROM Sessions s
    JOIN RegistrantSessions rs ON s.ID = rd.SessionID
    WHERE rs.EventID = @EventID
    GROUP BY s.ID, s.SeatLimit
    HAVING COUNT(rs.*) < s.SeatLimit
)
SELECT s.*
FROM Sessions 
INNER JOIN EligibleSessions es on es.ID = s.ID
WHERE s.EventId = @EventId 
      AND s.SessionTime = @SessionTime 
      AND s.SessionType = @SessionType 
      AND s.Active = @SessionActive
```

There seems like an extra layer of nesting here, but I didn't want to have to include every field in the Sessions table in the GROUP BY.

You may need to repeat some of the `WHERE` conditions in the CTE. It's also weird to me for the `EventID` field to repeated in both Sessions and RegistrantSessions. Seems like an indication something is not normalized properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your table structure correctly, we could join a the count query as subselect too:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sessions
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT RegistrantSessions.SessionID
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionID) AS SeatCount
    FROM RegistrantSessions
    JOIN RegistrantSessions ON Sessions.ID = RegistrantSessions.SessionID
    WHERE EventID = @EventId
    ) AS regCounts ON regCounts ON Sessions.ID = regCounts.SessionID
WHERE Sessions.SeatLimit < regCounts.SeatCount
    AND EventId = @EventId
    AND SessionTime = @SessionTime
    AND SessionType = @SessionType
    AND Active = @SessionActive
```